# Groovy Script in SoapUI

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

When I'm running the following script in my SOAPUI, I'm getting error related to HTTPBuilder. Error is still there even after adding @Grab statement.

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(serviceEndPoint)
def scanResultFile = new File(testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("ScanResultFile"))

http.request( POST ){ req ->

headers.'Connection' = 'Keep-Alive'
headers.'User-Agent' = 'SoapUI 4.5.1'
requestContentType = 'multipart/form-data'

ByteArrayBody bin = new ByteArrayBody(scanResultFile.readBytes(), "application/octet-stream", "jobResult");
StringBody info = new StringBody(testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("JsonScanResult"), "application/json", java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity()
entity.addPart("info", info);
entity.addPart("jobResult", bin)
req.entity = entity
}
```

Any solution to run this groovy script in SOAP UI.

Comment: what error do you get? please specify.

Comment: getting classdefnotfound exception for HTTPBuilder. Alos  added the @Grab but nothing changed. Is there any way to create multipart post request in SOAP UI using groovy script?

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI does not come with `HTTPBuilder`. Further, since the Groovy engine has already been started in a running SoapUI instance, your `@Grab` annotation will not work.

In order to extend the functionality of SoapUI, you must download the .jar and **all dependencies** manually, and place them in `$SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext` folder. You will need to restart SoapUI for this to take effect.